# How to pass variable to UDAF (user define aggregation function)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType, pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os



@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def split(df, validation_period):

   ""Logic""

    return df

def train_test_split(spark, data_frame, request_json_data):

    data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(data_frame)
    print(data_frame.schema)
 

    validation_period = request_json_data['validation_period']
    groupby_key = request_json_data['groupby_key']

    data_frame.groupby(groupby_key).apply(split, validation_period).show()
```

Can't call split function it gives error. apply() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. I want to pass validation_period as argument to split function.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't pass extra argument to pandas grouped map udf since it excepts only a single pandas df as an argument.

Long answer: There are other ways you can pass validation_period to the function

1. use some form of a closure

   ```
   def split_fabric(validation_period):
       @pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
       def split(df):

           ""Logic""

           return df
   ```
2. pass it as a column

   ```
   data_frame \
       .withColumn("validation_period", F.lit(validation_period)) \
       .groupby(groupby_key).apply(split, validation_period).show()
   ```